# Using CefSharp when is the first and most effective opportunitiy to find out a PDF is being downloaded

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am currently trying some custom handling of PDF files. I want to open PDF's in a PDF application.  The issue I have with setting this in the CefSettings eg. CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-pdf-extension", "1") is that the website also shows PDFs at certain times within a panel. If "disable-pdf-extension" is set then this panel shows empty and of course the pdf opens in an external application.

Can I dynamically set "disable-pdf-extension"? Or can it only be set once at initialization?

What I am currently doing is to try and know when a PDF is being downloaded in OnBeforeBrowse, getting the URL, cancelling browse and using a HTTPWebRequest to download the file myself.

The question I have is that some of the URLs in my OnBeforeBrowse do not indicate whether they are PDFs.  So when is the first time I know the browser is going to show a PDF?  Currently I can see it in OnResourceResponse but is there something before this?

Out of interest does cefsharp "swallow" pdf files and decide to show them with the use of its internal pdf.dll or is it out of cefsharps control?

Comment: command line args cannot be changed at runtime, if you disable the PDF viewer it will be disabled for the lifetime of the app. CefSharp is just a wrapper around the `Chromium Embedded Framework`, it relies on the default behaviour to display PDFs. If you are relying on `MimeType` to identify a `PDF` then you'll have to wait for the initial response received in `OnResourceResponse`. You should be able to selectively control loading of `PDF` plugin using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContextHandler_OnBeforePluginLoad.htm

Comment: The `CefSharp` doco is a little out of date, see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestContextHandler.html#OnBeforePluginLoad(constCefString&,constCefString&,bool,constCefString&,CefRefPtr%3CCefWebPluginInfo%3E,PluginPolicy*)